# visual studio delete all breakpoints in a file

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to delete all breakpoints in a specific file (customerController.cs). Is there an easy way to do this?

I don't want to delete all breakpoints within a project or a solution.

Comment: Debug -> Windows -> Breakpoints, sort by name. You can select multiple breakpoints at once to toggle them.

Comment: I can't select breakpoints. Because there are many breakpoints.

Comment: @JeroenMostert You should mark this as a potential answer, it's more than likely the best solution considering the fact that you can shift + click an entire file's worth of breakpoints and disable them. (I actually didn't even know you could do this until now -- great answer)

Comment: @emert117 What's stopping you from selecting breakpoints?

Comment: @emert117: hold shift + cursor down. There may be many breakpoints, but you can select dozens of breakpoints per second this way... Actually, if you use "search" to limit the breakpoints shown to one file, Ctrl-A for "select all" will also work. Then hit delete to remove, or space to toggle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Open Breakpoints window (**CTRL+ALT+B**)
- Add File columns in Show Columns (optional)
- Search by file name
- Select all and delete

---

n.b. Talking about VS2017

Answer (score 4):

Addition to @Johnny's answer:

- Open Breakpoints window (CTRL+ALT+B)

[image: Open Breakpoints window]

- Add File columns in Show Columns

[image: Add File columns in Show Columns]

- Search by file name and Click "Delete all breakpoints matching the current search criteria"

[image: Search by file name]